# How to Extend Home Partiiton Size and With Some space from Root Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have 500Gb hard in which I am running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot mode. I have 2 partitions in ubuntu. `/home` and `/`. The problem which I am getting is that my `/home` partition is running out of space but my `/` partition has 90Gb free space. This is shown in below snapshot.

[image: enter code here]

I want to free some space from my `/` partition and give that to `/home` partition. I have seen a way with gparted but I cannot delete space from my `/` partition. Is there any way to do this.?

Answer (score 0):

You must handle it in two steps:
1. reduce some space at the left side from /dev/sda7.  This space will be "unallocated"
2. increase your /dev/sda6 with this unallocated space.

Note: this will take a while, espescially the first step.

Comment: How to reduce some space at the left side from /dev/sda7? I tried it but cannot reduce space from both sides.

Comment: I tried it with gparted.

Comment: You do not describe what you  really have done.  So i must guess. Have you unmounted the partiton?  Nevertheless here you will find a very good maunual of gparted:  http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual  .  Go to Advanced  partitions actions -  resizing a partition.   (+ see unmounting a partition)